# How to add styles to an excel column with xlsx javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I have to create an excel, from this array of objects, excel creates it perfect for me, now what I need to do is every time I find the name, which will be the beginning of each data, paint the column in some color Especially, I was looking everywhere, but the code is not very clear, I am using XLSX. Thanks a lot.

```
 async function JsonToExcel(archivo) {
 var archivo = [
{
  nombre: "Tomas",
  edad: 22,
  secundaria: true,
},
{
    nombre: "Cristian",
    edad: 23,
    secundaria: false,
  },
  {
    nombre: "Rodrigo",
    edad: 28,
    secundaria: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "Romina",
    edad: 27,
    secundaria: false,
  },
  ];
  const fecha = new Date();
  const fechatotal =
  fecha.getDate() +
  "-" +
  (fecha.getMonth() + 1) +
   "-" +
  fecha.getFullYear() +
   "_" +
  fecha.getHours() +
   "-" +
   fecha.getMinutes() +
   "-" +
   fecha.getSeconds();
   const workbook = await XLSX.utils.book_new();
   const worksheet = await XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(archivo);
   const unificadoExcel = await XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(
   workbook,
   worksheet,
   "Hoja1",
   true
   );
  // console.log("Este es el resultado de unificado: ", workbook.SheetNames)
  const nombreArchivo = `unificado-${fechatotal}.xlsx`;
  const rutaArchivo = `api_operaciones/files/unificados/${nombreArchivo}`;
   XLSX.writeFile(workbook, rutaArchivo);

   return nombreArchivo;

  // console.log("Archivo creado con exito");
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
const colName = ['A1', 'B1']
for(const itm of colName} {
   worksheet[itm].s = { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: "7A7A7A" } }, font: { color: { rgb: "FFFFFF" } } }
}
```

Note: install https://github.com/gitbrent/xlsx-js-style

Full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bh9ihy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: const workbook = await XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const colName = ['A1', 'B1']
  for(const itm of colName) {
    const worksheet = await XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(datareporte);
   worksheet[itm].s = { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: "7A7A7A" } }, font: { color: { rgb: "FFFFFF" } } } 
   // console.log("Este es el resultado de unificado: ", workbook.SheetNames)
  }
  const unificadoExcel = await XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(
    workbook,
    worksheet,
    "Hoja1",
    true
  );

Comment: Excuse me, can you write it as an answer with the code you provide? I'm trying what you wrote, but it gives me several errors.

Comment: For you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bh9ihy?file=src/app/app.component.ts